# What spells did Harry and Draco use in the bathroom battle scene?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

When the fight kicked off, Malfoy attacked Harry and Harry attacked back **with which spell/charm?**

I'm uncertain because they didn't speak the words of the spell.

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty convincing, covering both the novel and the film. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 10):

In the book it was [Levicorpus](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Levicorpus), the same spell used to hoist Snape into the air in Snape's flashback

> Malfoy wheeled round, drawing his wand. Instinctively, Harry pulled
> out his own. Malfoy’s hex missed Harry by inches, shattering the lamp
> on the wall beside him; Harry threw himself sideways, **thought
> Levicorpus! and flicked his wand,** but Malfoy blocked the jinx and
> raised his wand for another –
>
> ‘No! No! Stop it!’ squealed Moaning Myrtle, her voice echoing loudly
> around the tiled room. ‘Stop! STOP!’
>
> There was a loud bang and the bin behind Harry exploded; Harry
> attempted a Leg-Locker Curse that backfired off the wall behind
> Malfoy’s ear and smashed the cistern beneath Moaning Myrtle, who
> screamed loudly; water poured everywhere and Harry slipped over as
> Malfoy, his face contorted, cried, ‘Cruci—’
>
> ‘SECTUMSEMPRA!’ bellowed Harry from the floor, waving his wand wildly.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince: Chapter 24 - Sectumsempra</sup></sub>

---

In the film, they appear to be using wordless [stunning spells](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Stunning_Spell).

[image]

Comment: I just watched HBP BlueRay yesterday and you can clearly hear Harry using Sectumsempra to badly hurt Draco before Snape appears and heals him. But the rest of the spells can't be made out clearly.

Comment: @ward - The gif is illustrative and doesn't need removing because you personally don't like it.

Comment: "Illustrative" is a stretch.  There's no sound, so it's not obvious that the spells are wordless, and how does it show what the spells are?

Comment: @Ward - It shows Harry using a stunning spell wordlessly. I don't see how it could be any more illustrative without containing a subtitle that says "see, stunning spells can be used wordlessly".

Answer (score -1):

Harry : Levicorpus, Sectumsempra. 
Malfoy: Blocking spell, Crucio.

Snape, in movies - Vulnera Sanatur, the healing charm.